# Get Java on Roomba ( Robotics )

Tags: java, robotics

Question is how can I get to work with Roomba using Java?

Comment: What have you done so far besides asking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RoombaComm](http://www.dprg.org/projects/2009-07a/) is a Java library for communicating and controlling the Roomba. It works on  Mac OS X, Linux, and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily program the roomba in java!  True, the roomba doesn't have much memory on its processor to really do... anything - haha, but you can use its SCI command interface to send it motion commands.

Thus if you use a separate device to program in java, and then use a simple serial cable to relay the motion commands you wish the roomba to do, then you should be good!

Any sort of microcontroller will work & what's nice about the serial port on the roomba is that you can source power (5v) from it as well to power your controller.  One way I recomend is to get a rootooth to play around with.  It's a bluetooth adapter for the roomba and will allow one to play around with the device while not being constrained with wires.

Either way, the serial interface is pretty basic.  This website has a good introductory overview of how to control the roomba with the serial commands:
http://www.robotappstore.com/Knowledge-Base/1-Introduction-to-Roomba-Programming/15.html

You can either transfer data to a host computer, or even just stick your computer on the robot and have it do a bunch of things!

Hope this helps!